# Syntax Error in SQL statement (2)

Tags: sql, vba, jet

I am trying to run this SQL statement in a VBA macro but for some reason it won't run due to a syntax error that I cannot seem to pinpoint.  I am rather new to VBA so any help in pinpointing this error would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim dte As String, db As Database, tableName As String, DataDump As Recordset, clientTable As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
dte = InputBox("What date was the Data Dump run?", "Please Input a date")
tableName = "FN_DataDump_ALL_" & dte
Set DataDump = db.OpenRecordset(tableName, dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)
Set clientTable = db.OpenRecordset("Clients", dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)

MySQL = "SELECT DISTINCT DD.[Client ID] " & _
        "INTO Clients " & _
        "FROM " & tableName & "as DD " & _
        "Where CL.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT DD.[Client ID] ""FROM"" &  tableName & ""as DD"") "

db.Execute MySQL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Misplaced quotes around `FROM` and a missing space produced `TABLENAMEAS`, instead:

```
= "SELECT DISTINCT DD.[Client ID] " & _
        "INTO Clients " & _
        "FROM " & tableName & " as DD " & _
        "Where CL.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT DD.[Client ID] FROM " & tableName & " as DD)"
```

Comment: Thank you! One more thing, if the table already exists can I `SELECT...INTO` it?

Comment: You would use INSERT INTO in that case.

Comment: So would I just change `SELECT` to `INSERT`?